# How to count the number of incoming calls a specific number has in callLog.calls? ANDROID QUERY CALL LOGS

Tags: android, sqlite, count, calllog, querying

I have a phonestatelistener which retrieves the incoming call number
what i want to do is to have that certain number queried and checked in the callLog content provider and get the number of incoming calls that specific number has made on a specific date

and with that, i want to check also if that number has the most incoming calls for the specific time given, if yes, only his calls will ring, otherwise, no ring will be heard

the app actually considers the person with the most incoming calls as a frequent caller,
if he qualifies, then he will be considered an important contact and his calls will ring

my problem is, how do i do it in a query?? heeelpp!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code as

```
   Uri urlcall = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls/");
   Cursor receivec = null;
   receivec = HomeErasor.this.getContentResolver().query(urlcall,
                null, "TYPE='" + CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE + "'", null,
                null);

   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
```

//here you will get all information like number and date compare same number with different date and that date should be as you want.( CALLLOG.CALL.DATE return time+date ) by comparing this you will get how many times that number called you.

```
            String num =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
            String queryString = "_ID=" + num;
            // Log.v("_ID", queryString);               
            // use value
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: i had already queried it that way but the idea is, i want to get only the incoming calls from a specific date, when i add in WHERE CallLog.calls.DATE >= todaysDate (which is a date value turned string and with format dd-MM-yyyy), 

i also want to know and get the person with the most incoming calls for the day, can you help? i really need this for next week, thanks!

Comment: hey man! thanks, i got another question tho,
how do i put my date filter in the where clause ? should i do it like this?
CallLog.Calls.DATE + " >= '" + todaysDate + "'" 

todaysDate is a string since CallLog.Calls.DATE accepts string, it has a format of (dd-MM-yyyy)  

is this correct? or is there something to be changed???

Comment: you cant write directly CallLog.Calls.DATE its a column name which is of type long. by using getLong() method you can fetch value from database and then compare it with ur current date,that long value can give u time and date both


you can use SimpleDateFormat class to retrive that data in specific date +time format.there are different date format you can use it as your requirement.

Comment: yes, i've already done the query that gets all the incoming calls in that specific date, now the only thing left to do is. . 
how do i use that query, to get the number with the most incoming calls? can u make an example query? 
like SELECT * NUMBER from callLogs where type=incoming and date>todaysDate and max(TYPE) << is that how to do it?

Comment: i actually asked a different question so it'd be clearly understood, if u can, pls check it out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774111/how-to-get-the-number-of-the-most-frequent-value-entry-in-calllog-calls