# How to get most frequently used calls from call log in android?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider, calllog

Is there any method or query to display all most frequently used calls from call log can be display in one list?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

You could create a wrapper for Log.d/w/e etc and have it keep track of the number of times it encounters each log, then you would be able to figure out the most frequently used calls by sorting your data.

It's a clean way to do it, since you wouldn't need to change anything else.

I wanted this functionality before, but I found that in most cases if I restructured my log calls under conditional statements, I'd get what I wanted without the noise.

You can also create some temporary gui elements in your app to display the same information, or even do away with your log calls and just increment integers in their positions, then do one big log call in the end to see which integer is incremented the most - ie: which log call would have been called the most in its place.

Comment: Thanks for replied Steven Huang. i tried by using this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774111/how-to-get-the-number-of-the-most-frequent-value-entry-in-calllog-calls" but it is not displaying appropriate output